# Flutter: layout question regarding column child height

Tags: flutter, layout

I have a layout where I want to expand a widget (container) to the right, it's the red area in the examples. To the left of the expanded container there is a column with an image at the topleft (blue in examples) and a button in the bottom of the column. I do know the button width, it's a bit over 100 pixels but we can assume that it's 100 pixels if that helps.

The thing is that the blue area (it's a user uploaded image) can vary in size. From e.g. 100x100 to 800x800. It will be square and smaller than 100x100 is not supported. Large images are resized to 800x800.

I want to achieve this:

- The column should adapt it's size depending on the image size.
- The column should be as wide as needed by the button but otherwise 100 <= width <= 400 depending on image size.
- The column should not overflow in any direction.
- The red area should be maximized.
- The button should always be at the bottom left of the layout.
- I cannot know the column height in advance without using a LayoutBuilder and I want to know if this is achievable without calculating the exact height in pixels using a LayoutBuilder.

Here's an example of how I want it too look with a small image (100x100) and that works with the code below the image: [image: 100x100 image (blue)]

Code that works well for 100x100 image:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          width: 800,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildColumn(),
              Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildColumn() {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildImage(),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Fixed height button'),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImage() {
    // This can vary from 100x100 to 800x800 (always square)
    var size = 100.0;
    return Container(color: Colors.blue, width: size, height: size);
  }
```

If I bump it to an 800x800 image by changing the size variable to 800.0 in _buildImage() I get this layout: [image: 800x800px without height constraint]

I understand that the column have unconstrained height on it's children so it will render the blue container with 800px height which creates the overflow. I do know that the column height is 400px in this case and that the button is 48px high so I can calculate that the max image size is 352px in height. By wrapping the blue container in a Container with constraints (maxWidth: 352, maxHeight: 352) I achieve the layout that I want:[image: perfect fit for large image]

```
  Widget _buildImage() {
    // This can vary from 100x100 to 800x800 (always square)
    var size = 800.0;
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 352, maxHeight: 352),
      child: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: size, height: size),
    );
  }
```

I can also achieve this using expanded, like this:

```
  Widget _buildImage() {
    // This can vary from 100x100 to 800x800 (always square)
    var size = 800.0;
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: size, height: size),
    );
  }
```

I want to avoid using calculated pixels for height/width so lets continue with the Expanded widget. When I have that expanded widget with a small image, i.e. 100x100 I get this result (which is not what I want): [image: expanded problem with small image]

I need to align my blue square within the expanded widget to prevent it to getting stretched but when I do that (align top left), like this:

```
  Widget _buildImage() {
    // This can vary from 100x100 to 800x800 (always square)
    var size = 100.0;
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: size, height: size),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then I get this result: [image: blue is right size but red is not expanded]
The container outside of the blue container expands and makes the column unnecessary wide. I want to have the same look as the first image when I have a small image.

How can I achieve this adaptive layout without using a LayoutBuilder and calculating exact image constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the column with a container and set the height:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8;
```

it will contain 80% height in screen

Comment: Thankls but unfortunately this does not help me. The column already have a height. In this example I have it wrapped in a container with 400 height so setting it to mediaquery.height * 0.8 is the same as 400 px but based on screen height. The problem is that the column children cannot use this height without the Expanded (or Flexible) widget. And the expanded or flexible widget expands in both vertical and horizontal direction.